# Calling a static Func from a static class using reflection

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

Given the static class:

```
public static class Converters
{
    public static Func<Int64, string> Gold = c => String.Format("{0}g {1}s {2}c", c/10000, c/100%100, c%100);
}
```

I am receiving the `Func` name from a database as a string (`regEx.Converter`). How can I invoke the Gold `Func` using reflection? Here is what I have so far:

```
var converter = typeof(Converters).GetMember(regEx.Converter);
if (converter.Count() != 1)
{
    //throw new ConverterNotFoundException;
}                    
matchedValue = converter.Invoke(null, new object[]{matchedValue}) as string;
```

**Edit:**

I should have mentioned that I plan on adding other Funcs to my `Converters` class that may take different parameters.

**Edit2:**
From the replies so far, I have it working for the Gold `Func` below. I suppose my question now is, how do I make this work when I don't know the parameters of the `Func`. For example, I may want to create another converter as so: `Func<string, string>`. The only thing I can be certain of is that there will only be one parameter (of differing types) and the return will always be string.

```
var converter = typeof(Converters).GetField("w", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
if (converter == null)
{
    //throw new ConverterNotFoundException;
}
var f = converter.GetValue(null) as Func<Int64, string>;
matchedValue = f.Invoke(Convert.ToInt64(matchedValue));
```

Comment: Will it *always* be a `Func<Int64, string>`?

Comment: The specific Gold one will be but I plan on adding others that will take different parameters.

Comment: I've edited my answer to include some thoughts on this, but it may be worth considering if it won't be easier just to switch on regEx.Converter and keep things strongly typed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify BindingFlags to get static members:

```
var converter = typeof(Converters).GetMember(regEx.Converter,
    BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
```

You could also simplify this by using `GetField` if it will never be a property:

```
FieldInfo converter = typeof(Converters).GetField(regEx.Converter,
    BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
```

Edit:
I'm not sure it'll be much help as you'll still need to know what sort of arguments to pass the `Func<>`, but this will let you invoke the `Func<>` without casting it:

```
var matchedValue = converter.GetValue(null);
matchedValue.GetType().GetMethod("Invoke")
    .Invoke(matchedValue, new object[] { Convert.ToInt64(0) });
```

And to get the type of the argument:

```
matchedValue.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0];
```

You should consider the possibility that it will be easier to `switch` on the field name and avoid reflection altogether.

Comment: Given that he seems to only be calling from a known class, I would heavily recommend a `switch` or similar method, going to reflection is overkill in this case.

Comment: @Guvante I agree, it's likely overkill and overcomplication.  I'm working on the assumption that it's possible there's some other requirement we don't know about making the direct approach more difficult.

Comment: Hey, thanks guys. There's no other requirements past what you see. What I was concerned about is that I might need upwards of 100 converters and wanted something a bit more succinct that a switch for every case.

Comment: @ChrisO In that case I'm not sure there's a really good way to do it.  Whichever way makes the most sense to you will probably be the best.

Answer (score 2):

Since it's not a function or a property, you cannot invoke the member like that. You should get its value first, cast it as appropriate, and only then invoke the result, like this:

```
var converter = typeof(Converters).GetField(regEx.Converter);
var f = converter.GetValue(null) as Func<long,string>;
var matchedValueString = f(matchedValueInt);
```